# Sencha Touch work flow

Tags: testing, sencha-touch-2

I have started working in Sencha Touch 2.1.1. I would like to know the following:

- What is the best work flow for a Sencha Touch app during development? Testing in Chrome may not give the actual mobile view. How can I test my app on Windows during development?
- xtype 'label' is not getting resized when I change the browser size.
- After changing the code each time I come to Chrome and refresh, but it takes a few seconds to load the app. Is there any quicker way?

Comment: Are you using sencha-touch-debug-all.js for dev or the microloader ? Are you using Compass to compile you CSS ?

Comment: using microloader, No for Compass.

Comment: Because then you're probably linking all Sencha's CSS where you would only need just a part of it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Host you app using WAMP or some we server and open it on you mobile
   device is you are using same WiFi.
2. please attach screen shots
3. Its not an Egyptian magic, it will take few seconds pal...

Comment: Ok for 1. but the rest is not really helping